# Python: urllib2 get nothing which does exist

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, urllib2

I'm trying to crawl my college website and I set cookie, add headers then:

```
homepage=opener.open("website")
content = homepage.read()
print content
```

I can get the source code sometimes but sometime just nothing.

I can't figure it out what happened.

Is my code wrong?

Or the web matters?

Does one `geturl()` can use to get double or even more redirect?

```
redirect = urllib2.urlopen(info_url)
redirect_url = redirect.geturl()
print redirect_url
```

It can turn out the final url, but sometimes gets me the middle one.

Comment: Rather than checking just the content, try checking the status of the response. If you send too many requests in a short period of time, it might be that the server is blocking you and/or closing the connection.

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini Yeah, it work! ! :D but i get a question. why python2.x remove urllib2 module, and use urllib?(i think urllib2 is upgrade version...)

Comment: @Hugo the urllib of Python 3 is an enhanced version of urllib2 of Python 2. You can think of it as "urllib3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than working around redirects with urlopen, you're probably better off using a more robust requests library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

```
r = requests.get('website', allow_redirects=True)
print r.text
```

Comment: doesnt work:(.each redirect response get a new cookie and post to the next in request..

Comment: i figure out a way to transmit cookies.